# Question for the Continuity and Isolated point

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

As far as I've known, if the $\{x_0 \}$ is a isolated point of the $X$, the smallest open set of the $x_0$ would be $\{x_0\}$. We can easily show the continuity by definition of it. So my conclusion is

> If the $\{x_0 \}$ is a isolated point of $(X,T_1)$ then $f : X \to Y$ is a continuous at $x_0 $ whatever any function $f:(X,T_1) \to (Y,T_2) $ is.

Next I'm tried to find the number of the continuous functions $f : (X,T_1) \to (Y,T_2)$, the case of like the below.

( $X=\{a,b,c\}$, $Y=\{3,4,5\}$, $T_1 = \{\phi, X, \{a\}, \{b,c\}\}$, $T_2 = \{\phi, Y, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{3,4\}\}$)

Clearly the $X$ has a isolated point at the $a$. Hence $f(a)$ can be no matter what the element of the $\{3,4,5\}$ is. So only left is finding the image of the $\{b,c\}$.
When the $f(b) =3$, $f(c)$ should be $3$ by definition of the continuity at $c$. With the same method, $f(b)= f(c) =4$ for the $f(b)=4$ case. Plus $f(b)= f(c) =5$  for the $f(b) =5$ case. Hence there can be $3$ cases of the image for $\{b,c\}$.

So my answer is $9$ because of the ($f(a)$ cases) $\times$ ($f\{b,c\}$ cases). Is my answer is right?

There is a claim answer is $7$. If it is true, I can't find the any point in my thought. Please let me know the errors if the answer is $7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ maps a point $x$ to an isolated $f(x)$, then $f^{-1}[\{f(x)\}] = \{x' \in X \mid f(x)=f(x')\}$ must be open, so indeed if $f$ maps $b$ or $c$ to $3$ or $4$ then $f$ is constant on $\{b,c\}$. As $a$ is isolated it doesn't matter where it maps to for continuity of $f$. So $b,c$ both map to the same point (could be $5$ too), so there are $3$ choices for those points and $3$ for $a$ as well. So $9$ continuous functions, out of all $27=3^3$ total possibilities. I cannot see where the $7$ would come from.